# What SIP voip client for OS X I could use?

Tags: software-recommendation, voip

I'm looking for a, preferably free, SIP client for OS X, one that will allow multiple SIP accounts and preferably supporting g729 audio codec.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer [Telephone App](http://code.google.com/p/telephone/) over most the other VOIP clients I have come accross.

Answer (score 2):

Blink is a decent free VOIP client for Mac OS, though I'm not sure about g.729 support.  For that you may need to look at something like Mirial.  They have a Mac version but it doesn't have the Mac feel, and I think its expensive.  Bria might be another commercial option as well.